# Trigger krunner with Meta

Tags: kubuntu, krunner

as the title suggests, I want to trigger krunner with Windows/ Meta key. I followed [this](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tips#open-krunner-with-windows-meta-key) instruction, but didn't work. For confirmation, I logout and log back in, also tried rebooting the system, didn't work.

plasmashell version > 5.24.7, OS > Kubuntu 22.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Information was out-of-date in [KDE UserBase Wiki](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tips#open-krunner-with-windows-meta-key).

Correct command is `kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta "org.kde.kglobalaccel,/component/org_kde_krunner_desktop,org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component,invokeShortcut,_launch"`, which is followed by `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure` respectively. [The D-bus path has changed](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/13re9rh/comment/jljuhgz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). All credit goes to redditor [u/hexchain](https://www.reddit.com/user/hexchain/).